# Dynamic variable passed to exec

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork, exec

I'd like to get your opinion on this.
I'm writing a program. During some fixing up and testing, I realized I'm forgetting to free a piece of memory I'm using. So I did, but the problem is that it now throws a SEGFAULT (but it works fine w/o the free).

1. allocating and assigning value

```
        char* device = (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        if (device == NULL){
            printf("[-] Bad pointer to devicePath. exiting..\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        device = "nvme";
```

2. pass onto function (which forks and exec)

```
        searchPathForDisk(device, devicePath);
```

3. trying to set free

```
        free(device);     //causes SEG FAULT - why?
```

I thought it had something to do with the exec not finishing executing before I'm calling free, but that's not the case.
Any ideas? Is it something related to exec?

Comment: Why are you mallocing when you immediately assign a string literal to `device`?

Comment: On another couple of notes: 1) `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be equal to `1`, no matter the actual bit-width of `char`; And 2) In C you [shouldn't really cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You basically have `device = malloc(...);` followed by `device = "nvme";`. What do you think happens with the second assignment? Where will the pointer `device` be pointing? If you want to copy a string you should use `strcpy`.

Comment: Why allocate 10 bytes to hold a 5-byte string?

Comment: If you must allocate dynamically, for whatever reason, use `char *device = strdup("name");`

Comment: sizeof(char) - just common pratice.
and I'm assigning string literal to device just for the local testing porposes.
it will obviously will not be the case once everything is set.